# How can i get ngRoute to work in Cordova App

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, angular-routing

I am using angularJS in my Cordova App, and while i am trying to use $route in my app to navigate through different modules. I was not able to get it running even when i have angular route js referenced in my page.

Here is my html page html:

```
<div ng-app="mainApp">
        <a href="/module1">module1</a>
        <a href="/module2">module2</a>
        <ng-view></ng-view> 

        <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
        <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
        <pre>$route.current.params = {{$route.current.params}}</pre>
        <pre>$route.current.scope.name = {{$route.current.scope.name}}</pre>
        <pre>$routeParams = {{$routeParams}}</pre>   
    </div>


    <script src="scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/frameworks/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my module definition:

```
// define all your modules
var module1 = angular.module("module1", []);
var module2 = angular.module("module2", []);

// Lastly, Add all other modules after defining the main module
angular.module("mainApp",
    [
        'module1',
        'module2',

    ]

    );
```

My Controller code:

```
module1.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.Test = "This is a test message...";


    $scope.$route = $route;
    $scope.$location = $location;
    $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for using $route in AngularJS cordova app is the following:
1) Reference angular-route.js in your html page.
2) Add ngRoute as dependency for your module ( This was the missing piece).

In my mainApp module, i need to add ngRoute is a dependecy to load ngRoute functionality while loading my module, therefore my controller code for referencing $route will work.

updated module instantiate:

```
angular.module("mainApp",
    [
        'module1',
        'module2',
        'ngRoute',
    ]

    );
```

Hope this helps.